# getUserMedia - how to stop camera access if I've lost my reference to the stream?

Tags: webrtc

I haven't lost it; it's right here.  But for some reason, calling the following doesn't always turn my webcam's light off:

```
stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
    track.stop();
});
```

I don't know if it's a timing issue or what, but I'd like some way to just brute-force the closure of whatever streams are accessing hardware.  Is this API available?